How to chunkify the Kusto query for small intervals and aggregate finally for the big interval?
I have a query like this:
TableA
| where env_time > ago(30d)
| where Name in ("A" "B", "C", "D", "E")
| where Client == "Android"
| summarize count() by UserId, Name
It works fine for 1 day interval, but the volume is so much that running it for greater than 1 days, times out the query.
How do I rewrite in a way - Run the query for 1 day intervals for the last 30 days, and then do a join on the individual 30 day summarizations so that I get the overall data?

What is the size of your total data in rows and in storage wise?

size would be in Tbs

Try with the below query for chunkify the Kusto query for small intervals and aggregate finally for the big interval.
Instead of querying the entire 30-day period at once, it breaks it up into smaller chunks, one for each day, so that the query processes each day independently. This prevents timeout issues caused by processing too much data in one go. The join function links the TableA data with the range table, which holds the daily intervals. After joining the individual daily summaries, the query aggregates the counts from each day using summarize.
Now you can get total number of occurrences of each UserId and Name across the 30 days, without having to run a query that processes all 30 days in a single step.
let dailySummaries = range DaysAgo from 0 to 29 step 1
| join kind=inner (
    TableA
    | where Name in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
    | where Client == "Android"
    | summarize dailyCount = count() by UserId, Name, DaysAgo
) on DaysAgo
| summarize totalCount = sum(dailyCount) by UserId, Name;
dailySummaries

Output:


I don't think it would work. The query on the TableA inside the JOIN specifies no date range. So the inner query will run for the whole table.
Also, how can you summarize on DaysAgo, I am getting syntax errors.
